# Jquery .clone can't set named function as event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a method that will copy the HTML from another part of the page and then set a click handler for the elements inside of it. Problem I'm having is that the handler is not firing when clicked.

Its funny because when I set the handler as an anonymous function, it fires when clicked, but when I set it to either self.initSizeSZ or myModule.initSizeSZ it won't fire.

```
// Elements are cached for performance. 
var $selectSizes = $('#someSelector');
var $catalogWheels = $('#someOtherSelector');

var myModule = {
    // This is the module that calls renderSizeSZ
    loadWheels: function(){
        if(!this.loaded){
            this.renderSizesSZ();
            this.loaded = true;
        }
    },
    renderSizesSZ: function(){
        var self = this;
        var $clone = $selectSizes.clone(false);
        var html = $selectSizes.html(); 

        $catalogWheels
            .find('#icf_catalog-sizes')
            .html(html)
            .find('li a')
            // if this is set as an anonymous function, it will fire, but as a named function it won't
            .click(self.initSizeSZ);
    },
    initSizeSZ: function(event){
        console.log('firing')
    }
}
```

Comment: This is using jQuery 1.11.3

Comment: How is `renderSizesSZ` being called?

Comment: .click(self.initSizeSZ);

Comment: No, how is **`renderSizesSZ`** being called?

Comment: There's another method in the module that calls it. I'll edit the question to include that method

Comment: Hmm well I don't see anything suspicious in that; if you're not seeing any errors in the console then it's not apparent what the problem might be.

Comment: You're sure it works EXACTLY as-is if you just change it to an anonymous function and make no other changes?  Perhaps some other change was made in addition that is the actual problem?  For example, you mention clone and even use it in your code, but nothing ever happens with the cloned element.

Comment: I used .clone because I thought that was the best way to copy HTML without passing on the event handlers from the original element. Maybe I should just use .html()

Comment: [**This**](https://jsfiddle.net/73pd7shz/) seems to work just fine. The problem must be somewhere else. I know this seems stupid, but is `#icf_catalog-sizes` actually present in `$catalogWheels` ? Is the content actually being cloned ?

Comment: Though I don't think it has bearing on this issue given what you've posted, cloning content with "id" properties is problematic, as "id" values need to be unique in the document.

Comment: I don't know what could have caused this with .clone, but I switched to .html() and the problem went away. I wonder what could have caused this.